# Which way is better for update database record?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two method for update:

```
String query = "update mytable set name = 'new_value' where id ='20' ";
Connection conn;
PreparedStatement pState;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");
    pState = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pState.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException sql) {
    sql.printStackTrace();
}
```

OR:

```
String query = "update mytable set name = ?" + "where id = ?";
Connection conn;
PreparedStatement pState;
int s;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");
    pState = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pState.setStringt(1, "new_value");
    pState.setString(2, "20");
    s = pState.executeUpdate();       // if s = 1 then update done successfully
} catch (SQLException sql) {
    sql.printStackTrace();
}
```

Both methods update database record correctly, Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the second approach.

You aren't *returning* anything, so why create a result set and go down that path?

**Edit:**

Even after your comment, I would still use the second template. It's more flexible. Additionally, it's faster. The PreparedStatement is pre-compiled in the database which allows the database to execute a parametric query using the statement faster than a normal query. This won't happen if you use string concatenation (like in your first example).

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Additionally, from that page:

> The main feature of a PreparedStatement object is that, unlike a
>   Statement object, it is given a SQL statement when it is created. The
>   advantage to this is that in most cases, this SQL statement is sent to
>   the DBMS right away, where it is compiled. As a result, the
>   PreparedStatement object contains not just a SQL statement, but a SQL
>   statement that has been precompiled. This means that when the
>   PreparedStatement is executed, the DBMS can just run the
>   PreparedStatement SQL statement without having to compile it first.
>
> Although PreparedStatement objects can be used for SQL statements with
>   no parameters, you probably use them most often for SQL statements
>   that take parameters. The advantage of using SQL statements that take
>   parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with
>   different values each time you execute it.

Answer (score 3):

Second approach is good practice to avoid S[QL Injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

And following is enough to construct query String, another + concatenation is not required.

```
 String query = "update mytable set name = ? where id = ?";
```

Answer (score 1):

The second way is more faster if you use frequently the same query. Depends of the database vendor, the query is cached and the efficiency is higher than that using flat sentences. But all that depends on the implementation of the JDBC driver and  the services provided by the database.

See more in [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in the [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).